# React mdbootstrap mdb.min.css confict with my own css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Due of this line in de mdb.min.css file:

[image]

My header is completed messed up and the items are not perfectly align centered.

[image]

When you turn off `margin-top: 0;` it works completely fine. I decided to delete this line in the mdb.min.css. But after launching my server with npm start, when I look in inspect element, the line: `margin-top: 0;` keeps coming back even after I deleted this line in the mdb.min.css file.

Like I said I tried to delete this line in mdb.min.css file. In my own css file for the header I used: `align-items: center;` but it doesn't change anything, even if I add `!important`. Why is this `margin-top: 0;` still coming back even after I deleted it ? And why is my css for centering the items in de header not applied ? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my javascript code:

```
import classes from "./Navbar.module.css";
import UserComponent from "./UserNavComponent/UserNavComponent";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const HeaderComponent = (props) => {
    return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <nav className="nav">
        <ul className={classes.navList}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Text2Read</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/History">History</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className={classes.loginContainer}>
            <UserComponent></UserComponent>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default HeaderComponent;
```

and here is my css file:

```
header{
  background-color: #1F1F20;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: #252526;
}
header nav{
display: flex !important;
flex-flow: row nowrap !important;
align-items: center !important;
justify-content: space-between !important;


}
.navList{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.navList a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;

  padding-top: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffff !important;

}

.navList a:hover{
  background-color: #027DF0 !important;
  transition: 0.5s !important;
} 
svg{
  color: #ffff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
select{
  width: 100px;
}
.loginContainer{
  padding-right: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  min-height: 88vh;
}
```

Comment: In your css module `header` is not referring to a class. It should be `.header` to match what you're using in the component. That's why its affecting the global style rather than being scoped locally to the component.

Comment: @Andy I tried, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you do the same for `nav`? Maybe then remove the `!important` props because you probably don't need those any more.

Comment: @Andy I did, but still doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Did you change `<nav className="nav">` to `<nav className={classes.nav}>`?

Comment: @Andy Yes, I did.

Comment: What happens when you remove all the CSS you're not using in that component like `main`, for example?

Comment: @Andy Only the dropdown menu, on the right, is a little bit smaller, but for the rest the items left of the header are still not centered aligned.